# Logical and bitwise operators VB

Tags: vb.net

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) The `And` operator can act as a bitwise operator OR a logical operator.

The only way to know if it is used as One operator or another is, If it is on the right side of an assignment operation? for example `x = 3 AND 5`. I cannot find any other instances where the bitwise operator would be used instead of the logical operator, are there? Thank you for you help.

Update: I guess you can do it inline if you needed to

```
    Response.Write(CLng("3") And CLng("4"))
```

Comment: My understanding is that the "and" operation is logical when in boolean context, and bitwise when in numeric context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a logical operator when the operands are both of type Boolean.  Bitwise operator in any other case, albeit that I'm not trying to think of Nothing.  Also consider `OrElse` and `AndAlso`, they are always logical and do short-circuit evaluation.